# How to find number of palindrome within given string in PHP?

Tags: php

Looking for below kind of output as per given input

```
$string = "how are level";
```

so output would be

> Word Count :- 1 & it's "level".

```
$string = "how are level level";
```

> Word Count :- 2 & it's "level".

So it will count how many words are palindrome in string with it's count

Sample code i have tried

```
function checkPalindrome($string){
    $reverse =  '';
    $results = array();
    $array = explode(" ",$string);
    foreach($array as $word){
        $reverse = strrev($word);
        if($word == $reverse){
             $results[]= $word;
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
$string = "How many level we have level i"; // Input String/Parameter for function
$result = checkPalindrome($string); // Call function

print_r(array_count_values($result));
if(count($result) > 0){
    echo "Palindrome word is:";
    foreach ($result as $rWord){
        echo "<br /><b>".$rWord."</b>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a simple explode and use strrev function to check and update a counter

Answer (score 3):

If it is ok to explode by space, do this:

```
$words = explode(' ', $string);
$count = 0;

foreach($words as $word) {
    if(strrev($word) === $word) {
        $count++;
    }
}

echo $count;
```

You'll probably explode using ",", "." and other chars.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
<?php
$str="hi helo how wow are you level level";
$word=explode(" ",$str);
$count=0;
foreach($word as $val)
{

 if($val==strrev($val))
 {
   $count++;
 }
}

echo $count." time pallindrum found in <br>$str";
?>
```